# How do determine how much bandwidth a process is using in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, bandwidth

On occasion I see my [bandwidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth) usage using **gnome-system-monitor** going up to 300kbit/s. I just can't figure out what is causing it. I want to know what process or program in using my network like that?

I do ssh into different machines and servers, where I would really like to be able to monitor bandwidth usage. It would be very useful to know which utilities people use to see what [bandwidth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth) is being used and by which applications / programs / processes / or threads. I don't even know where to start looking.

The two small programs I have found are insufficient. [bmon](http://freshmeat.net/projects/bmon/) and [bwm-ng](http://www.gropp.org/?id=projects&sub=bwm-ng) 
And tools like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) ([packet sniffers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer)) are overkill. I would like something in the middle, preferably text console-based.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
iptraf
```

or

```
iftop -P
```

to identify connections that consume much of your bandwidth. A connection is identified by a pair of (localip:port, remoteip:port). You can then use

```
netstat -tunp
```

to look up what process uses that connection. Mostly however, you will be able to tell what service is responsible only by looking at the port, e.g. if the connection uses `localip:80` on the local side its probably your webserver ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Well, there is `iftop` but that only shows the source and destination, not the program causing the traffic.

Edit:

Just found `nethogs`. It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/)

It works well showing which ip / hosts the bandwidth is being used by. It can isolate the information down to a single program or port.

> sudo Iftop

once it is running you can the access the help menu with H or ?. Which has numerous useful options

```
Host display:                          General:
 n - toggle DNS host resolution         P - pause display
 s - toggle show source host            h - toggle this help display
 d - toggle show destination host       b - toggle bar graph display
 t - cycle line display mode            B - cycle bar graph average
                                        T - toggle cummulative line totals
Port display:                           j/k - scroll display
 N - toggle service resolution          f - edit filter code
 S - toggle show source port            l - set screen filter
 D - toggle show destination port       L - lin/log scales
 p - toggle port display                ! - shell command
                                        q - quit
Sorting:
 1/2/3 - sort by 1st/2nd/3rd column
 < - sort by source name
 > - sort by dest name
 o - freeze current order

iftop, version 0.17
```

Answer (score -3):

The [SSH System Administration Tool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshadmincontrol/files/) has facilities for bandwidth monitoring.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question... If this program does it, include instructions